# Image of a circumference by a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm doing this exercise and I don't know how to finish.

Consider the vector function $F(x,y) = (x^2+y^2, 2xy)$. Determine the image of the circumference $x^2+y^2 = a^2$, $a>0$, and obtain the image of all $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I wrote $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=2xy$ and so we have $|v|\le u$. To determine the image of the circumference I did $u=a^2$, thus $-a^2\le v\le a^2$. How can I conclude anything from here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means u is a constant, while v can vary within those bounds.  So the image is a segment in uv space.

Comment: For starters, what can u not be?